# Is there an NSCFTimer memory leak?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

I tracked down a memory leak with instruments. I always end up with the information that the responsible library is Foundation. When I track that down in my code, I end up here, but there's nothing wrong with my memory management:

```
- (void)setupTimer {
    // stop timer if still there
    [self stopAnimationTimer];

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(step:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    self.animationTimer = timer; // retain property, -release in -dealloc method
}
```

the property animationTimer is retaining the timer. In -dealloc I -release it.

Now that looks like a framework bug? I checked with iPhone OS 3.0 and 3.1, both have that problem every time I use NSTimer like this. Any idea what else could be the problem?

(my memory leak scan interval was 0.1 seconds. but same thing with 5 seconds)

Comment: what does `stopAnimationTimer` do? I think you need to invalidate the timer (and I hope you're doing it in your `stopAnimationTimer` method).

Comment: yep, it just invalidates the timer and sets the property to nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your `stopAnimationTimer` method is `invalidate`'ing and `release`'ing (and then setting to `nil`) your `animationTimer` property, you're leaking memory.

Comment: You mean `release`'ing instead of `dealloc`'ing, don't you?

Answer (score 5):

Do not call `-[NSTimer dealloc]`. Ever.

In this case, `-scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` is balanced by `-invalidate`. You do not need to call `-dealloc` or `-release` on the timer object.

Comment: +1 Should be right, if `invalidate` does `release` the timer afterwards. Because he uses `self.animationTimer = timer;` this will first release the old and then retain the new value and therefore this should be leak-safe.

Answer (score 1):

I found it: I had a strong reference to my timer. The run loop retains it. So RC was 2. But because the Timer also holds a strong reference to the target (which in my case retained the timer), I had a deadlock situation. -dealloc was never ever called, and therefore my timer was never ever freed. WTF.